# How to retrieve active positions using CCXT library on Kucoin exchange?

Tags: python, ccxt, kucoin

I can get all open orders (take profit or stop loss ), but I dont know if some position is "open".

```
Positions = exchange.fetchPositions(symbols = 'SOL/USDT:USDT', params = {})
```

I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'kucoinfutures' object has no attribute 'fetchAccountPositions'
```

Sometimes, there is an active trade and if I want to put another position and a tp/sl, two things happen: If the position is contrary to the previous one and if they have the same amount, simply the previous position is cancelled, and the new position enters.

But when the amount of the new position is different from the previous position and if the amount of the TP/SL is calculated to the amount of the new position, there would be an open position after a TP or SL occurs, with the remaining amount, there is an open position.

Comment: Looks like you forgot to post the Python code that's causing you a problem

Comment: I don't know what code I could put, I try with this code "exchange.fetchMyTrades(simbol)" but I don't get what I really need, if someone knows how to put an example code

Comment: You need to add the code that's causing you problems to the question - a minimal reproducible example

Comment: Please edit your question to include a code block and/or error message in the body of question. [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: Have you tried to get information about positions currently held as describred in this section of ccxt docs? https://docs.ccxt.com/en/latest/manual.html#positions

Comment: Positions = exchange.fetchPositions(symbols = 'SOL/USDT:USDT', params = {})
it returns me error:
AttributeError: 'kucoinfutures' object has no attribute 'fetchAccountPositions'

Comment: have you tried `positions = exchange.fetchPositions()` ?

Comment: yes and the same error comes out

Comment: ok it works for me on binance. i'll setup an account on kucoin later and try it there later on.

Comment: Ok, very good Alex B, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work for you or do you still get an error message?

```
import ccxt

exchange = ccxt.kucoinfutures({
    'apiKey': [...],
    'secret': [...],
    'password': [...],
    'enableRateLimit': True,
})

markets = exchange.load_markets()
positions = exchange.fetchPositions(symbols = 'SOL/USDT:USDT', params = {})
print(positions)
```

Comment: if it works now, incredible, I don't know why it didn't work yesterday. Thanks to all for the help :)

Comment: @maxixmo you're welcome. Please accept the answer as correct and upvote if you can. I have the feeling you were using `fetchAccountPositions` instead of `fetchPositions` maybe.

Comment: could you fetch all positions without specifying symbols